# Row count by group

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, rowcount

I am attempting to write the following query to get a row count by group.

```
select  
  a.employee, a.cov_option, 
  count(a.cov_option) over (partition by a.cov_option order by a.employee) as row_num
from wilson.benefit a
inner join wilson.bncategory b 
  ON a.plan_type = b.plan_type and a.plan_option = b.plan_option 
inner join wilson.bncovopt c 
  ON a.company = c.company and a.plan_code = c.plan_code and a.cov_option = c.coverage_opt
where 
  a.plan_type = 'HL' and 
  to_char(a.stop_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '1700-01-01' 
order by a.employee, a.cov_option
```

The result set returned is:

```
employee     | cov_option   |row_num 
-------------|--------------|--------------
429          | 1            | 1 
429          | 3            | 2
429          | 3            | 2
1420         | 1            | 2
1420         | 3            | 4
1420         | 3            | 4
1537         | 2            | 2
1537         | 2            | 2
```

The result set I am attempting to return is:

```
429          | 1            | 1 
429          | 3            | 2
429          | 3            | 2
1420         | 1            | 1
1420         | 3            | 2
1420         | 3            | 2
1537         | 2            | 1
1537         | 2            | 1
```

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about why you think the observed values are incorrect and why you think the expected result is correct?

Comment: @John - the OP doesn't "think" the "expected result" is correct; he is telling us the "expected result" is the **required** result.

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback. As mathguy stated, the expected results are required and they a correct. I am attempt to count the rows, but only change the value when the cov_option and employee change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want is `dense_rank()` rather than `count()`. Indeed, "count" means simply determining how many rows are in each group, it is not "counting" in the way we learn as children (first, second, third). That kind of counting is called "ranking".

```
dense_rank() over (partition by a.employee order by a.cov_option) as row_num
```

should do what you need.

There is also `rank()` - the difference is that if two rows are tied for first, with `dense_rank()` the **third** row gets rank 2; with simple `rank()` it gets rank 3 (rank 2 is "used up" by the first two rows).

Comment: your solution solved the issue. I do appreciate your help and explanation. I will also look into rank() so that I have a full understanding. Thanks again.